# Split a String builder into a Strings bu Specific char

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Im sending to android separate massages:
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n 
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n 
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n.

But getting it randomly when connection established into a buffer readMassage which is could be 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n 11 22 33 4 and then next time connection established getting rest 4 55 66 77 88 \r\n 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n Im not missing any characters but ....  But have to some how parse it to the right separate  massages.

So what I need to do is split this builder into a String by `\r\n` and send it farther like that `11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n`. - bang

But The thing is here that I need *not only separate them* first but also somehow *capture last part* of the first read after `\r\n` which is in this example `11 22 3` and then concat it to first part of the second read all the way up to `\r\n` which is this example : `3 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n`

Basically on one connection session it could be 2 and half Str String to to send.

```
public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG2, "run start");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];  // buffer store for the stream
        int intBytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        StringBuilder readMessage = new StringBuilder();



        while (true) {
            try {
                intBytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);// считываю входящие данные побайтно из потока
                String readed = new String(buffer, 0, intBytes);   //и собираю в строку ответа


                    readMessage.append(readed);

           if(readMessage.toString().contains("\r\n")){


               String Str = readMessage.toString();
               Str = Str.replace("\n", "");

                // DO SOMETHING HERE with Str So the on one  readMessage it could be two different Str to send in farther. And part of the next Str save some how  

                      mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, Str.length(), -1, Str).sendToTarget();
                        readMessage.setLength(0);
```

Comment: Would you mind writing it clearer? Maybe you are looking for `substring(int start, int end)`. First one is inclusive, the 2nd one exclusive.

Comment: ok. yes. substring from point to point I will get first Str to send but what to do with the last part of the readMessage when you don't know when it's finished. I mean readMassage is everytime different length. Im sending to android like that its all difrent massages: 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n  11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n   11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n.    But getting it randomly  in the readMassage which is could be 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n 11 22 33 4 and then next time  connection created 4 55 66 77 88 \r\n  11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 \r\n Im not missing any characters  but ....

Comment: Never put more information into comments. Edit your question. Which you should do anyway. Hint : that preview window exists for a reason. To prevent you from dumping such a mess on the people you are about to ask to spend their time to help you with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()` method of String class like below:

```
readMessageString.substring(readMessageString.lastIndexOf("\r\n"), 
                            readMessageString.length());
```

and then prepend that substring to next String.

Hope it helps!